# Multiply submit in one form. More than 1 submit in one form. Or more then one form in 1 JSP

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, submit

I'm doing web-application. And I have a problem when I edit data

I want to create smth like this

[image: my idea]

I hope you can help me to find way to do this. I found next variant but I don't know as people  usually do this.

1. Multiply submit in one form.
2. More than 1 submit in one form.
3. Or more then one form in 1 JSP

And I should't use any framework. And without javascript.

Thanks

OK, If It helps to understand what I want to get on servlet 
I show some part of selvlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String page = new String();
        Command command = CommandFactory.getCommand(request);

        page = command.execute(request);
        if (page != null) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(page);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
          ....
}
```

And CommandFactory

```
public static Command getCommand(HttpServletRequest request){
        Command current = new NoCommand();

        String action = request.getParameter("command");

        if(action == null || action.isEmpty()){
            return current;
        }

        try{
            CommandEnum currentState = CommandEnum.valueOf(action.toUpperCase());
            current = currentState.getCurrentCommand();           
        }
...
}
```

And CommandEnum

```
public enum CommandEnum {

    EDIT_QUESTION {

        {
            this.command = new EditQuestionCommand();
        }
    };
}
```

And in particular command I do some business logic

Please, help me to find way getting from jsp value as command="delete". With single submit I use hidden field. How we can do the same for several button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any number of submit buttons in a single form. But name them uniquely so that you can identify easily which button is clicked. Server will not receive name, value pair of buttons that are not clicked. It becomes easy for you to find which button clicked is available as request parameter. Using that you can implement your requirement.

**Sample HTML**:

```
<form>
 <input type="submit" name="s1" value="S1"/><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="s2" value="S2"/>
</form>
```

On clicking any of these buttons you will see query string as either `?s1=S1` or `?s2=S2`

**UPDATE 1**:
You can have same name for all submit buttons and to identify uniquely, they MUST have different values.

```
<input type="submit" name="modeOfAction" value="Delete"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="modeOfAction" value="Update"/>
```

**UPDATE 2**:
If you really don't care what the *value* of each button, then it would be better using unique names for each of the submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить (Err! I don't know what this text is!)"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"/>
```

Comment: @Ray - Give a name to your submit button to receive it at server. Here you only labeled it's click can't be recognized by server.

Comment: In pages I have one submit-button. I use next constraction
`<form  action="/TutorWebApp/controller" method="POST" name="loginForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login" />Login:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="login" value=""/>               
        .....             
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>                
</form>`
        
It means that I should write 
`<input type="submit" name="command" value="????" ` and there I have a question. In controller I get value command by name command. But in page I should write value="Удалить" ( in my language).

Comment: if I write 
**`<input type="submit" name="command=edit_question" value="Edit" />`**
            
I can get after that in servlet "edit_question" for particular command as
            
**`String command = request.getParametr("command");`**
            
 there **command = "edit_question"**
            
 or not?

Comment: @Ray - You require to set the charset as `UTF-8` to see `Удалить` as value of the submit button. This should be in your meta tag. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: That is the long-standing problem of `<input>`, that `value` is also the display text. Without JS changing some hidden input with name command, that is not possible.

Comment: @Ravinder No, I haven't problems with encoding. I want to get by name "command" value for example **"edit_question"** on servlet when I do **request.getParametr("command");**

Comment: @Ray - As explained by Joop Eggen, answer is No. `<input type="submit" name="command=edit_question" value="Edit" />` is bad practice. You require to separate name and values but not join as part of the input name. With your example you need to code like `String command = request.getParametr("command=edit_question");` But the reply would be `Edit` but not `command=edit_question`.

Comment: @Joop Eggen but if user turn off JS. What will be next? I believe that      should be way to do this without JS

Comment: @Joop Eggen Please, Can you give me example on JS? ( for this case). But I believe to find way without JS

Answer (score 0):

There was a time when indeed the optional JavaScript meant: gracefully accept when no JavaScript is present. With the small devices one might think this position might be strengthened again, but:

- HTML forms are limited in their usage, as shown above a bit.
- DOM usage, like AJAX calls updating part of the page, need JS.
- JavaScript user interface possibilities (effects, table sorting, paging, themes, validation) with libraries like jQuery.

I still now a way to get a `command=edit`: write a *servlet* filter that translates request parameters. For instance translate a parameter **command-*NAME* = *TEXT*** into **command=*NAME***.